Align cursor rotation to normal
In edit mode, I'm trying to move a number of faces in the direction of the normal of one of the selected faces.
I figured that one way to do this is to set 'Transform Orientation' to 'Cursor' and rotate the cursor such that it aligns with the normal of the relevant face... but is there a way to do that?
Or is there some other easy way to achieve the same thing?

The 3D cursor, when moved with ShiftRMB-drag, can be Ctrl snapped, so the settings on the left below will at least align its Z to face normal:

But, as an aside, IMO, the 3D cursor tool is still pretty poorly integrated, so, for instance, the ShiftS snap to selected doesn't respect the tool setting: 'Align to Geometry', among other irritations.
So personally, I always have 'Create Orientation', (the little plus in the right hand panel, above), set in my Q quick favourites menu, with 'Overwrite Previous' and 'Use After Creation' set in its F9 panel, so as not to pile up created orientations.
That has the advantage that you can create a Z direction from a face or any 3 vertices, or a Y direction from an edge or any 2 vertices. (Excess defining selections will use a mean direction.) The keyboard , comma shortcut can quickly restore previous transform orientations.

Pretty good trick, thanks! Indeed, I found your 'Create Orientation' solution (which is more convenient for 'rare' use I guess).
I'll see if I can make a change request to add rotation to 'shift+s', that seems the way it should be working.
